# Are there any editors to help develop AIML (artificial intelligence markup language)?

Tags: editor, artificial-intelligence, aiml

im starting work on a chatbot and have decided to use AIML for the sentence interpretation. 
Please recommend any editors or GUIs to help create AIML.

Answer (score 0):

The [Gaitobot AIML editor](https://www.gaitobot.de/gaitobot/AIMLEditor/infos.aspx?lang=en) gets good reviews from the community, but the [Simple AIML Editor](http://riotsw.com/sae.html) is also nice.